# .NET , .Setting configuration file does not return updated configuration

Tags: .net

I have an assembly (.dll)  project "EpmTfs.Common" which has a  UtilityConfig.Settings file ( .Settings file) containing some configuration settings.  To access the configuration values i am using the code like

string pwd  = Common.UtilityConfig.Default.passWord;
string userName = Common.UtilityConfig.Default.userName;

The console application "EpmTfs.Console" uses functions defined in EpmTfs.Common. On build , the utilityConfig file is copied to the bin directory of Console application. Everything works fine.

Problem is, when i copy it to production and change the value of userName and passWord. The utility returns the old password which was defined in the UTilityConfig file during build time. This is true even after i change the values in the UtilitConfig file in production.

So my problem is, how do i change these values in production without requiring a build on dev.

[image]
PS:  I know there is a way to have different config files for different environment, but cant i simply edit this file in production ?

Answer (score 0):

By default it's only the config file for the executable application that provides settings for the whole application. Which means that the generated `*.dll.config` file for the accompanying assembly is not read during runtime. At least not automatically.

One solution to fix this is to include the settings for the class library in the `*.exe.config` file. We can do this by defining a section for the class library in that file. It's just a matter of copy-pasting some rows from the generated class library config to the application config.

Here's an application config file where I merged the application config and a class library config. This file gets copied side-by-side the executable with the `*.exe.config` extension and the `MySettingInAssembly` setting will be passed to the settings instance in the class library during runtime.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="ClassLibrary1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <applicationSettings>
        <ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="MySettingInApplication" serializeAs="String">
                <value>SomeValue</value>
            </setting>
        </ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings>
        <ClassLibrary1.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="MySettingInAssembly" serializeAs="String">
                <value>MyValueFromApplication</value>
            </setting>
        </ClassLibrary1.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```